# How to specify which GCP project to use when triggering a pipeline through Data Fusion operator on Cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to to trigger a Data Fusion pipeline located on a GCP project called `myDataFusionProject` through a Data Fusion operator (`CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator`) inside a DAG whose Cloud Composer instance is located on another project called `myCloudComposerProject`.

I have used the [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/datafusion.html) as well as the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datafusion.py) to write the code that roughly resembles the below snippet:

```
LOCATION = "someLocation"
PIPELINE_NAME = "myDataFusionPipeline"
INSTANCE_NAME = "myDataFusionInstance"
RUNTIME_ARGS = {"output.instance":"someOutputInstance", "input.dataset":"someInputDataset", "input.project":"someInputProject"}

start_pipeline = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
    location=LOCATION,
    pipeline_name=PIPELINE_NAME,
    instance_name=INSTANCE_NAME,
    runtime_args=RUNTIME_ARGS,
    task_id="start_pipeline",
)
```

My issue is that, every time I trigger the DAG, Cloud Composer looks for `myDataFusionInstance` inside `myCloudComposerProject` instead of `myDataFusionProject`, which gives an error like this one:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://datafusion.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myCloudComposerProject/locations/someLocation/instances/myDataFusionInstance?alt=json returned "Resource 'projects/myCloudComposerProject/locations/someLocation/instances/myDataFusionInstance' was not found". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo', 'resourceName': 'projects/myCloudComposerProject/locations/someLocation/instances/myDataFusionInstance'}]"
```

So the question is: **how can I force my operator to use the Data Fusion project instead of the Cloud Composer project?** I suspect I may do that by adding a new runtime argument but I'm not sure how to do that.

Last piece of information: the Data Fusion pipeline simply extracts data from a BigQuery source and sends everything to a BigTable sink.

Comment: I think you can specify the `project_id` when using `CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator`. On the [code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datafusion.html) scroll up to `CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator` and you will find that you can set `project-id`. Have you try it?

Comment: I ended up noticing that parameter too, I don't know why I missed it... And now it works :) Can you write your idea as an official answer so that I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a recommendation while developing operators on airflow, we should check the classes that are implementing the operators as documentation may lack some information due to versioning.

As commented, if you check `CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator` you will find that it makes use of a hook that gets the instance base on a `project-id`. This project-id its optional, so you can add your own `project-id`.

```
class CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(BaseOperator):
 ...

    def __init__(
       ...
        project_id: Optional[str] = None,   ### NOT MENTION IN THE DOCUMENTATION 
        ...
    ) -> None:
        ...
        self.project_id = project_id 
        ...

    def execute(self, context: dict) -> str:
        ...
        instance = hook.get_instance(
            instance_name=self.instance_name,
            location=self.location,
            project_id=self.project_id, ### defaults your project-id
        )
        api_url = instance["apiEndpoint"]
        ...
```

Adding the parameter to your operator call should fix your issue.

```
start_pipeline = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
    location=LOCATION,
    pipeline_name=PIPELINE_NAME,
    instance_name=INSTANCE_NAME,
    runtime_args=RUNTIME_ARGS,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    task_id="start_pipeline",
)
```

As a final note, besides the [official documentation site](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/) you can also explore the files of apache airflow on [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow).